# AWS Cloudformation - CodeCommit - Deny Push to Master

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-codecommit

So here is the situation:
I have a Cloudformation that creates CodeCommit repositories with some extra resources for other devops processes to work.

I got the requeriment to block users from doing a push to a specific branch, in this case master, I have found the policy that does that. source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-conditional-branch.html

So I write a role and policy with the following:

```
Resources:
  CodeCommitRepository:
    Type: AWS::CodeCommit::Repository
    Properties:
      RepositoryName: !Sub '${ProjectCode}-${ProjectName}-${ComponentName}'
      RepositoryDescription: !Ref CodeCommitRepositoryDescription
      Tags:
        - Key: fdr:general:project-code
          Value: !Ref ProjectCode
        - Key: fdr:general:project-name
          Value: !Ref ProjectName

  DenyPushRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub '${ProjectCode}-${ProjectName}-${ComponentName}-DenyPush-Role'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Ref DenyPushToMasterPolicy
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
              - codecommit.amazonaws.com

  DenyPushToMasterPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: !Sub '${ProjectCode}-${ProjectName}-${ComponentName}-DenyPush-Policy'
      Description: Policy to deny push to master
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
        - Action:
          - codecommit:GitPush
          - codecommit:PutFile
          - codecommit:DeleteBranch
          - codecommit:MergePullRequestByFastForward
          Effect: Deny
          Resource: !GetAtt CodeCommitRepository.Arn
          Condition:
            StringEqualsIfExists:
              codecommit:References: 
              - refs/heads/master
            'Null':
              codecommit:References: 'false'
```

As I understand which I wouldn't say is much, by creating the Role with the Policy and the sts:AssumeRole I thought that any user using that repository will assume that role that denys them the ability to push to master but that wasn't the case.

I guess that we may be overcomplicating things and we should put that policy unto all users directly on IAM but the idea is to have it done very granular. What am I doing wrong or is it even possible?.

Best regards

Comment: What's wrong with the template? Any errors?

Comment: I'm not getting error it just doesn't work... It should deny users to push to master to that specific repository and it just doesn't work, probably I'm commiting a basic mistake here, I'm pretty noob still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DenyPushRole` is not for any users. You specified it to be only for `codecommit.amazonaws.com` which is **incorrect**.

Users do not automatically assume any roles. They have to **explicitly** assume your `DenyPushRole` using [AssumeRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) API call. Your users must also have permission to `sts:AssumeRole`.

Thus your role, in a general form, should be:

```
  DenyPushRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub '${ProjectCode}-${ProjectName}-${ComponentName}-DenyPush-Role'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Ref DenyPushToMasterPolicy
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            AWS: 
              - !Ref AWS::AccountId
```

Once the role exist, and the users have `sts:AssumeRole` to assume it, they will use the `AssumeRole` command to actually assume the role. This will give then new,  temporary AWS credentials to perform any actions specified by the role. In your case, **the role only denies**, so they will not be able to do anything anyway. You would need to add some `allow` statements to the role for your uses to be actually able to do something, not only `deny`.

Comment: Sorry for not answering early, I was on a mini vacations till today, I will be taking a look unto this maybe today or tomorrow. But I'm guessing that "I" will not be able to achieve the porpuse if I'm not mistaken, this would have to be done globaly by Security (which manage the users) instead of acting only on individual Repositories, but I will try to understand it, thanks in advance this will help me look at right direction I hope!

Comment: As I was afraid I had a error in my understanding on how the AssumeRole could work, I wrongly thought that you would assume a role if a policy has pointed to a resource then you would assume that the policy of that role, but no, as you say a user must Assume the role, por example with aws-mfa with --assume-role using the API Call, at the end we will attach the policy to a Group, I can attach the policy via CFN with each individual Stack of repositories or directly make a policy to goes to all repositories and then add to the group the users needed. Thanks Marcin for your help!